# Can I use the JAXB2 Basics plugin with the MOXy JAXB implementation from EclipseLink? If not, is there an alternate?

Tags: xml, jaxb, java-metro-framework, jaxb2, moxy

Ultimately I want JAXB to generate hashCode and equals implementations. The JAXB2 Basics plugin does that and it works fine for the Metro JAXB implementation in the JDK but fails with MOXy.

I get:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBinder.updateXML(JAXBBinder.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBinder.updateXML(JAXBBinder.java:126)

MOXy works fine for me otherwise, i.e. if I get rid of the equals and hashCode generating code, everything is good.

Comment: I'm the MOXy lead and we are currently investigating the issue you are seeing.  Just to confirm the error you are seeing is with a JAXB model generated with the Basics plug-in when it is used with the JAXB Binder?

Comment: Hi Blaise, I debugged it and figured it out myself. It won't work. I'll explain why in a bit.

Comment: I think we have it figured out.  We're putting a fix together now.

Comment: Awesome. I'm around so let me know if you'd like to know what I found. Thanks for this.

Comment: If you could add what you have found to the following bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/347466) it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

We have submitted a fix for this issue into our EclipseLink 2.3.0 stream.  You will be able to obtain a nightly download from the link below starting May 28, 2011:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

The issue you are seeing is due to a bug in the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation of Binder.  We are currently working on a fix.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/347466

**For More Information on Binder**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html